# Add random values in array based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, foreach

I have input

```
record = {
    "Data": [{
            "Name": "ABC",
            "Result": "PASSED"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYZ",
            "Result": "FAILED"
        }]}
```

Now I want to convert in in `{'PASSED': ['ABC'], 'FAILED': ['XYZ'], 'Values':[]}`

But when I use below code

```
name_keys = ['PASSED', 'FAILED']
transformed_result = {}.fromkeys(name_keys + ['Values'], [])
for each_result in record['Data']:
    result = each_result['Result'].upper()
    if result in name_keys:
        transformed_result[result].append(each_result['Name'])
        print(transformed_result)
```

I get

```
{'Values': ['ABC', 'XYZ'], 'PASSED': ['ABC', 'XYZ'], 'FAILED':  
['ABC', 'XYZ']}
```

I am using python3. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
record = {
    "Data": [{
            "Name": "ABC",
            "Result": "PASSED"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XYZ",
            "Result": "FAILED"
        }]}


out = {'Values': []}
for d in record['Data']:
    out.setdefault(d['Result'], []).append(d['Name'])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Values': [], 'PASSED': ['ABC'], 'FAILED': ['XYZ']}
```

Comment: Does it take too much time to execute? @Andrej Kesely

Comment: @Vivek It shouldn't be, appending to the list is fast - depends how many items do you have.

Comment: This answer does not explain what the issue is and blindly proposes a different solution. The OP is not learning how to fix his issue.

Answer (score 1):

Could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here to group `Result` by `Name` into lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

record = {
    "Data": [{"Name": "ABC", "Result": "PASSED"}, {"Name": "XYZ", "Result": "FAILED"}]
}

d = defaultdict(list)

for r in record["Data"]:
    d[r["Result"]].append(r["Name"])

# Add empty list
d["Values"]

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'PASSED': ['ABC'], 'FAILED': ['XYZ'], 'Values': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you initialize the `transformed_result` dictionary, python first creates a new list (the last argument in the `.from_keys` function) and then it assigns this list to all entries of the dictionary. You can check it is always the same list by printing its id:

On my computer:

```
>>> id(transformed_result['PASSED'])                                                                                                                                                                    
140079882748464 

>>> id(transformed_result['FAILED'])                                                                                                                                                                    
140079882748464
```

Or also:

```
>>> transformed_result['FAILED'] is transformed_result['PASSED']
True
```

So, to solve your problem, you need to give a different list instance to each entry. Just change the above line into:

```
transformed_result = {key: [] for key in name_keys + ['Values']}
```